# Read values from text file

Tags: unity, importing

I'm trying to read the data from a text file with numbers  separated by tab.  And store those numbers in a list of float for example.  So that I can then use that list on runtime.  Any easy way of doing this?

Comment: Search for phrase "C# read CSV". In your case comas will be changed to tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text file in question is present at compile time, then in Unity I'd recommend including it in your Assets folder as a [TextAsset](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextAsset.html). That makes Unity do the work of managing the file, and gives us simple access to the data inside. :)

Anything with one of these extensions is automatically imported as a TextAsset, though you can customize this:

```
.txt   .html   .htm    .xml    .bytes    .json    .csv    .yaml    .fnt
```

Now you can assign this asset to a script's `public TextAsset myTextAsset;` field, or load it dynamically at runtime with [Resources.Load()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) just like working with other Unity assets you might be familiar with.

Then, when a script needs to convert this to a list of numbers, you can do...

```
// Split the text into an array of strings, cutting wherever there's a tab.
string[] numberStrings = myTextAsset.text.split('\t'); 

// Prepare a float array of the same size.
float[]  numbers = new float(numberStrings.length);
for(int i = 0; i < numberStrings.length; i++)
   numbers[i] = float.Parse(nuberStrings[i];
```

The above will also work for a local file selected by the user at runtime, or one downloaded from a server, though in that case you'll likely be getting the text from a [WWW object](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) instead of a TextAsset, but they both have a `text` property containing the text contents of the file so it's very similar.

Comment: Great reply I understand it perfectly, I'll try to create a similar script using lists instead. I wonder how can I pass the text or import it once the application is running,  like a different text. Although the main problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

```
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\Where the file is.txt"))
{
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {

        char[] delimiters = new char[] { '\t' };
        string[] parts = line.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(parts[i]);
        }

    }

    file.Close();
}
```

This piece of code opens up a file, reads all its lines and uses the [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method with the correct delimeiter(requested by OP). [StringSplitOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) is used to tell the Split method to ignore empty spaces within the splits. Then I use a simple [for](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) loop to log each element of the array to the unity console and of course close the file after we are done using it(cause I'm just nice like that)

Comment: Instead of just dumping a piece of code, could you also explain what it does and how? This would make your answer provide more value.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 OP did not request a explanation. He asked for a easy way to read values separated by tabs and I gave him a easy way to do it.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 better ?

Comment: Yes, of course. Code dumps are never good, even if the OP didn't ask for an explanation. However answers are much much more valuable and teaching when there's also an explanation.

Comment: Thank you uri that's seems quite easy,  I don't know why I can't upvote you

Comment: @user5723270 you probably lack the reputation to upvote. Its ok other people downvoted it because apparently its not good enough.

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions.